# Altering combineLatest to emit the result without awaiting other observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have this rxjs code where `cobineLatest` is used

```
cobineLatest(
  this.controls.toArray().map(c => c.changeEvent.asObservable())
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

The thing is that there won't be any result in subscription until all observables emits, I wonder how would you change that behavior so it will start emitting even if one single observable emits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to just pipe the single observables to start with `null`. This way you ensure that each observable has emitted at least one value:

```
cobineLatest(
  this.controls.toArray().map(c => c.changeEvent.asObservable().pipe(startWith(null)))
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are interested in the emitted value only (not the array), then [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) might be your friend.

```
merge(
  this.controls.toArray().map(c => c.changeEvent.asObservable())
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x); // x is not an array
});
```

Comment: merge returns only single value